# javascript variable to wordpress php variable

Tags: php, ajax, errors, variables

I need to push js variable into php variable. AJAX url is set via wp_localize_script but it returns ERROR 400 Bad Request. functions.php is looks like

```
wp_localize_script( 'script-js', 'compareids_ajax', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')) );
```

custom.js

```
 var compareIDs = $(".table td input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
          return $(this).val();
        }).get(); // <----
        $('.selected').text(compareIDs);
        console.log(compareIDs);



             $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",

                        url: compareids_ajax.ajax_url,
                        data: '{ compareIDs : compareIDs }',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (msg) {

                        },
                        error: function (errormessage) {

                        }
                    });
```

and my filter-page.php has

```
  <?php

                $compareIDs = array( $_POST['compareIDs'] );


    $args02 = array( 'post_type' => 'custom',
                     'post__in' => $compareIDs );

    $loop02 = new WP_Query( $args02 );

    while ( $loop02->have_posts() ) : $loop02->the_post();
    ?>
```

Comment: And where is the code that registers your hooks that will process that AJAX request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to to send function name as additional data as

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: compareids_ajax.ajax_url,
        data: {                             // Data object
              compareIDs : compareIDs,
              action: 'your_ajax_function'  // This is required to let WordPress know which function to invoke
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
              console.log( msg );
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
              console.log( errormessage );
        }
  });
```

In your php file

```
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_your_ajax_function','your_ajax_function'); // Ajax Function should be hooked like this for unauthenticated users
  add_action('wp_ajax_your_ajax_function','your_ajax_function'); // 

  function your_ajax_function(){

        $comparedIds = $_POST['compareIDs']; // Your data is now available in $_POST 
       // Do your stuff here

    die(); // At the end 

  }
```

See [wp_ajax_(action)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action))

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I actually did that but it seems there is no connection to the admin-ajax.php Its always 400 Bad request. Even if I just test it with the functions.php

```
          add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action');

           function my_action(){

            echo 'My action';

          }


   then enter http://my-website.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_action
```

the browser displays 0